# primality test binary

Tags: java, math

I'm generating numbers using a Java program (BigIntegers) and I want to know if there's a binary readily available that I could use to run primality tests on the numbers generated.... suppose I feed them through a pipe from my java program into the binary. Is it out there? I'm trying to find packages for aks on apt but I see nothing "straightforward", only libs that I could use to program stuff (like, based on GMP).

Answer (score 6):

#### openssl

The program openssl does primality tests:

```
$ a=31
$ openssl prime 31
1F (31) is prime

$ openssl prime 18446744073709551557      
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFC5 (18446744073709551557) is prime
```

The command is listed with help (`openssl help`):

```
$ openssl help 2>&1 | grep prime
pkeyparam         pkeyutl           prime             rand
```

And the details of the actual command are given by (`-help` or `--help`):

```
$ openssl prime -help
Usage: prime [options] [number...]
  number Number to check for primality
 -help         Display this summary
 -hex          Hex output
 -generate     Generate a prime
 -bits +int    Size of number in bits
 -safe         When used with -generate, generate a safe prime
 -checks +int  Number of checks
```

Very long numbers are also possible (2^521)-1 (Mersenne number with 157 decimal digits):

```
$ time openssl prime $(BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc <<<'2^521-1')
1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
(6864797660130609714981900799081393217269435300143305409394463459185543183397656052122559640661454554977296311391480858037121987999716643812574028291115057151)
is prime

real    0m0.042s
```

Two other utilities not connected to openssl but related to primes are:

---

#### Primes and factor:

> primes     - generate primes in a range
>   factor     - factor numbers

```
$  echo $(primes 10 50)
11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47

$ openssl prime 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47
B (11) is prime
D (13) is prime
11 (17) is prime
13 (19) is prime
17 (23) is prime
1D (29) is prime
1F (31) is prime
25 (37) is prime
29 (41) is prime
2B (43) is prime
2F (47) is prime

$ factor 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47
11: 11
13: 13
17: 17
19: 19
23: 23
29: 29
31: 31
37: 37
41: 41
43: 43
47: 47

$ factor 18446744073709551557
18446744073709551557: 18446744073709551557

$ factor 18446744073709551559
18446744073709551559: 41 163 269 8807 1165112831
```

Quite close to the max (signed) 64 bit integer number:

```
$ printf '%X\n' 18446744073709551559 $(( (2<<63) - 1 ))
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFC7
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Comment: Note that GNU coreutils (like some other Unices such as Solaris) has `factor` but not `primes` (even though both were introduced in Unix v7 in the late 70s). FreeBSD `factor` seems to support larger numbers than GNU factor. ITYM `primes 10 50 | xargs -n1 openssl prime` instead of `openssl prime  primes 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47`

Comment: Good find about `openssl prime` BTW. It doesn't seem to be documented. Even the help message with the version on my system doesn't mention the `-generate`/`-bits` option. To find out about the `-checks` option (20 by default as seen in the code), you need to look at the `BN_is_prime_ex(3)` man page that says it _performs a [Miller-Rabin probabilistic primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) with nchecks iterations._

Comment: The primes I have reports BSD Games Manual, so yes it should be from BSD (one of them). But it fails above 32 bits, it lists as primes numbers like 65539 square (4295360521). The number of incorrect primes grows as closer it gets to 64 bits. So, the (February 3, 2008) BSD primes has at least this (important) bug.  @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: GNU factor support quite large numbers, from the manual: factoring the eighth Fermat number 2^{256}+1 takes about 20 seconds on the same machine. Assuming the large number option was compiled in (read info factor).

Comment: Note that before version 1.1.0, `openssl primes` accepted only one integer as argument (hence my `xargs -n 1` as I have an older version)

Comment: Really @StéphaneChazelas ? Open ssl 1.1.0 was released on (25 Aug 2016), close to a year ago. Openssl **must** be updated as soon as possible, there are **many** vulns to correct, it is presently at 1.1.0**f**, the fifth release of that version. Please update as soon as possible. And it is `openssl prime`, without the `s`.

Comment: `1.0.2l` was released the same day as `1.1.0f` with the same security fixes but without the new functionality. Most of today's (2017) _production_ systems will have a 1.0.x version, even some with a short release cycle like Ubuntu. For instance, ubuntu 16.04, the current LTS having been released in April 2016 (so very recently), won't have a 1.1, but you still get the security fixes (back-ported onto their 1.0.2g).

Comment: Good to know that you found out. However, most of today *production* servers will be in the 1.1.0 branch. [Debian stable, testing and unstable](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=openssl) (stretch, buster and sid) are all in the 1.1.0 branch. [Fedora 26 and rawhide](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/openssl/overview/) are both (of course) on the openssl 1.1.0 branch. All other descendants should update, or be in the process of updating. @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: Not knowing which is your (old) flavor, can't provide an opinion. Of course, you can find about many distros in distrowatch, like Ubuntu ([see the table](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=ubuntu) 1.02g) or mint ([see the table below](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=mint) 1.02g), maybe you are in some BSD which are usually in the older branches (a shame) ([FreeBSD](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=freebsd) 1.0.2 (undefined) for Free BSD version 11). @StéphaneChazelas